# intento actualizar dos registros al mismo tiempo en android studio y php pdo

Tags: php, android, mysql

Tengo  una  tabla  con los campos Id,respaldo,familia.Lo que  intento es  actualizar un registro de familia que  coincidan con el respaldo  ya que tienen el mismo  valor y que al tiempo de actualizar se actualicen los dos  valores tanto de respaldo  como de familia.

Anexo mi código  PHP.

```
<?php 
 require('conexion.php');

   $respaldo=$_POST['respaldo'];

    // Consulta de Usuarios en la base de  datos
      $consulta = "SELECT *
                         FROM tb_familia
                         WHERE respaldo= ?";
      $comando=$conn->prepare($consulta);
      $comando->execute(array($respaldo));
      $row=$comando->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

       if($row)
       {

        $respaldo=$_POST['respaldo'];
        $familia =$_POST['familia'];
        $code=$_POST['respaldo'];

    // Creando consulta UPDATE
    $consulta = "UPDATE tb_familia" .
        " SET respaldo=?,familia=?" .
        "WHERE respaldo=?";

     // Preparar la sentencia
    $cmd = $conn->prepare($consulta);

     // Relacionar y ejecutar la sentencia
    $cmd->execute(array($code,$familia,$respaldo));
    print json_encode(
        array(
            'estado' => '1',
            'mensaje' => 'Se actualizó  correctamente')
    );

      }
      else
      {
          print json_encode(
        array(
            'estado' => '2',
            'mensaje' => 'No se actualizó  por que no existe  un registro con este  código')
    );
 }
 ?>
```

**CODIGO ANDROID (JAVA)  PARA  ACTUALIZAR REGISTROS.**

```
  private void submitForm() {
    ActualizarFamilia(
            spbuscarfamilia.getSelectedItem().toString(),
            updaterespaldo.getText().toString(),
            etmodificacion.getText().toString()
    );
}

private void ActualizarFamilia(final String respaldo, final String code, final String familia ) {
    // Tag used to cancel the request
    String cancel_req_tag = "register";
    showLoadingDialog("Espere Actualizando ......");
    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            Config.URL_UPDATE_FAMILIA, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());

            try {
                hideLoadingDialog();
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                String estado = jObj.getString("estado");

                if (estado.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                    Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(updateFamilia.this," Actualización  en Familia  con  éxito",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    TextView v=(TextView)toast1.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                    v.setShadowLayer(0,0,0,Color.YELLOW);
                    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    v.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    v.setTextSize(20);
                    toast1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER,0,0);;
                    toast1.show();
                    Limpiar();
                    submitbitacoraActualizacionFamilia();

                } else {
                    hideLoadingDialog();
                    Toast toast2= Toast.makeText(updateFamilia.this,"No se Actualizó  por que no existe  Familia con este Id",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    TextView v=(TextView)toast2.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
                    v.setShadowLayer(0,0,0,Color.YELLOW);
                    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    v.setTextSize(20);
                    toast2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
                    toast2.show();
                    Limpiar();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Registration Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast toast3=  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast3.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER| Gravity.CENTER,0,0);
            toast3.show();
            hideLoadingDialog();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting params to register url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("respaldo",respaldo);
            params.put("respaldo",code);
            params.put("familia",familia);
            return params;
        }
    };
    // Adding request to request queue
    AppSingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(strReq, cancel_req_tag);
}


public void showLoadingDialog(String texto) {
    try {
        if (progressDialog == null) {
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        }
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setMessage(texto);
        progressDialog.show();
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        progressDialog = null;
    }

}

public void hideLoadingDialog() {
    try {
        if (progressDialog != null) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    } catch (Exception a) {
        progressDialog = null;
    }
}

private void confirmUpdateFamilia(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Está  seguro  que quiere Actualizar en Familia?");

    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    submitForm();

                }
            });

    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    Limpiar();
                }
            });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}

// INSERCIÓN EN BITÁCORA DE ACTUALIZACIÓN
private void submitbitacoraActualizacionFamilia() {
    InsertarbitacoraActualizacionFamilia(
            muestramensaje.getText().toString(),
            muestrausuario.getText().toString(),
            muestrafecha.getText().toString(),
            muestrahora.getText().toString()
    );
}

private void InsertarbitacoraActualizacionFamilia(final String Accion_Ralizada,  final String Usuario_ingreso, final String Fecha,final String hora) {
    // Tag used to cancel the request
    String cancel_req_tag = "register";

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            Config.URL_ADD_BITACORA, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error al registrar: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting params to register url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Accion_Realizada",Accion_Ralizada);
            params.put("Usuario_ingreso",Usuario_ingreso);
            params.put("Fecha",Fecha);
            params.put("hora",hora);
            return params;
        }
    };
    // Adding request to request queue
    AppSingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(strReq, cancel_req_tag);
}

public void Limpiar(){
    spbuscarfamilia.setSelection(0);
    etmodificacion.setText("");
}
public void onBackPressed() {

    return;
    }
  }
```

**Variable donde  capturo el mismo valor de familia  para  pasarle el mismo valor a  respaldo.**

```
            updaterespaldo=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etrespaldo) ;
            String modify=etmodificacion.getText().toString();
            updaterespaldo.setText(modify);
```

Comment: Y ¿cuál es el problema Sofía?

Comment: A.Cedano  el código  no me  actualiza los dos  registros, el log cat me dice  que  tengo error  en mi código  php

Comment: Precisamente, [edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/113765/edit) poniendo el mensaje de error que te da el log cat... de ese modo sabremos lo que está ocurriendo y podremos ayudarte mejor. Los mensajes de error son fundamentales en la resolución de problemas, para eso existen. Yo veo ya al menos un posible error, y que desde Android estás enviando dos valores con la misma clave `respaldo`: `params.put("respaldo",respaldo); params.put("respaldo",code);` No me parece una muy buena idea. Mejor enviarlo con otro nombre de clave, de otro modo no podrás diferenciarlo en PHP.

Answer (score 0):

A simple vista veo dos errores en tu código.

### 1er error

Falta un espacio en tu consulta de actualización:

```
$consulta = "UPDATE tb_familia" .
        " SET respaldo=?,familia=?" .
        "WHERE respaldo=?";
         ^aquí
```

Actualmente, la misma se construye así:

```
UPDATE tb_familia SET respaldo=?,familia=?WHERE respaldo=?
                                          ^¡ERROR!
```

Debería ser:

```
$consulta = "UPDATE tb_familia" .
        " SET respaldo=?,familia=?" .
        " WHERE respaldo=?";
```

### 2do error

Estás enviando dos veces la clave `respaldo` desde Android:

```
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("respaldo",respaldo);
        params.put("respaldo",code);
        params.put("familia",familia);
```

Sin duda que eso te va a traer problemas o posibles datos erróneos... ¿Cómo sabrá PHP cuál es el valor de `respaldo`  y cuál es el de `code`?

Debería ser:

```
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("respaldo",respaldo);
        params.put("code",code);
        params.put("familia",familia);
```

Y, en consecuencia, modificar esta línea en PHP:

```
    $code=$_POST['respaldo'];
```

por esto:

```
    $code=$_POST['code'];
```

Como estaba antes, si es que funciona, `$code` estaría tomando el valor del primer elemento del Map pasado desde Android.

> Aunque me pregunto si lo que quieres filtrar ahí no es el valor de la
>   columna `id`¿?

### Otra recomendación

Aparte de esos errores, siempre es bueno controlar tu código PHP: que la conexión no sea nula, que el statement se prepare bien, etc, etc. e ir construyendo una respuesta json adecuada para leerla en Android, de modo que la App no haga crack nunca, aunque haya un error del lado del servidor.  Con tu código actual, es posible que si la conexión a la bd no está disponible en ese momento o si ocurre otra cosa no controlada, la app salga inesperadamente, provocando una mala experiencia del usuario.